# PutExtra in android - returning null in Fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am having a problem with one of my arguments in **putExtra**.

**I am declaring like this:**

```
Intent upanel = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        upanel.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        upanel.putExtra("USER_ID",json_user.getString(KEY_UID));
                        upanel.putExtra("USER_FN",json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME));
                        upanel.putExtra("USER_LN",json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME));
                        upanel.putExtra("USER_PI", json_user.getString(KEY_PROFILEURL));
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(upanel);
```

**and in my fragment I am reciving them like this**

```
 userID = this.getArguments().getString("USER_ID");
        userFirstName = this.getArguments().getString("USER_FN");
        userLastName = this.getArguments().getString("USER_LN");
        userProfileURL = this.getArguments().getString("USER_PI");
```

userid, userfirstname and userlast name work fine, userProfileURL is always returning as `null`?

the value being sent is `/var/www/image/1.jpg`, the only thing I can think of is that it doesnt like the / characters? Is this likely and if so how do I escape this character?

Comment: Put a debug breakpoint at `startActivity(upanel);` and see what `upanel` will return. This will tell you if you'll get null in the result.

Comment: if some work with you , so the problem in the profileurl value it self

Comment: Bundle[{USER_FN=dave, USER_ID=1, USER_LN=test, USER_PI=/var/www/app/uploads/1/profilepic/1396633446541.jpg}] So the correct value is being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well this fixes it!

```
userprofileurl = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("USER_PI");
```

EDIT

Actually, I forgot to declare the put in my MainActivity, in my case the user process is loginactivity->mainactivity and the fragments are loaded from here, so initially I was setting them in my loginactivity and then not in my mainactivity to pass them to the fragment

a d'oh moment!